# How to create folders under the organization in Google Cloud Platform (GCP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I created a GCP account, accepted all licensing agreements.

I setup an Organization and a billing account, got that confirmed.

I am now trying to create a folder under the organization that was setup, and get a yellow warning ! triangle:

You do not have permission to create folders in this location.

Why?

---

How do I fix this?

When I go to any page in IAM it gives me warnings that I do not have permissions with anything related to IAM.  I can't grant myself any further permissions.

I am logging in as the same user that created the GCP account (which is a GSuite user).

any help would be appreciated.  There is no support of any kind direct from Google with a paid GCP account, I am pointed here.

Comment: Is your issue resolved?If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

In order to access the permissions to create folders perform the following steps:

1. Visit console.cloud.google.com
2. Log in as the Super Admin
3. In the TopAppBar, next to **Google Cloud Platform**, select the resource drop-down as-if you were going to switch organization units or resources
4. In the resulting pop-up, make sure **Select from** at the top left has the proper organizational unit selected, then from the top right click on the three vertical dots and select **IAM/Permissions**

As an alternative, you could simply follow the first 3 steps above and then

1. Click the menu stack at the far left of the TopAppBar, selecting from the navigation drawer the **IAM** sub-menu of the **IAM & Admin** menu option.

Next, in order to grant the proper permissions to the Super Admin:

1. Find the Super Admin in question from the list of IAM accounts, or alternatively you can add a new user or service account by selecting the appropriate action from the top of the view.
2. On the far right of the user in question, after the listed roles, click on the **pencil** icon that indicates *Edit principal*.
3. In the resulting drawer you have the option to edit the roles the user has, including adding new ones.

*Organizational Admin* provides almost every permission needed for managing resource, however it does not include creating Folders. For this, you need to scroll down in the list of Roles to **Resource Manager** (you can filter for "Folder", don't filter for "Resource" - it's confusing...I know) and on the Roles available for the category you can choose **Folder Admin** or **Folder Creator** to be able to create folders.

This may be a limitation of user accounts that were created before creating folders became available. I'm sure Google would never simply enable administrative privileges blindly, not even for current admins, just because they are newly created features.

In other words, I'm unsure if someone who created a GCP account now as a Super Admin would not have Folder Creation rights as an Organizational Admin - but if you happen to have that limitation as an Organizational Admin; the above is how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks 'Folder Admin' was the permission I needed in my case

Comment: Thank you! The way GCP is setup seems so overcomplicated. Coming from AWS I appreciate that GCP feels like everything was designed by the same team, but it still somehow manages to be less intuitive than AWS's mishmash of GUIs.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an organization, you are not automatically assigned permissions (roles) in the organization. You need to add roles to your IAM member account.

There are several roles to consider. For the Project Owner, add the role `roles/
resourcemanager.organizationAdmin` at the Organization Level.

[Access Control for Organizations using IAM](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org)

Also, review the roles Project Creator and Billing Account Creator

[Managing Default Organization Roles](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/default-access-control)

Comment: This is great information.  I went down this path, but I was denied granting myself any roles.  I was denied access to IAM screens and information.  How do I grant myself roles if I do not have access to IAM where roles are granted?

Comment: Also I'm not sure our admin would want to give me complete control over the organization (GSuite apps and all), but just within GCP, to be able to do anything, and everything there, and delegate admins to projects and folders.

Comment: I assumed since you created the organization that you were the Project Owner. In your case, you can use the Folder Admin role https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-folders

Answer (score 0):

As was already pointed out by John Hanley, you will need to have the correct permissions to  create a Folder in your [organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders#before_you_begin):

If you are not the Prooject Owner, ask your administrator to grant you permissions to your account to create folders, I see you follow the access_control manual, but be sure you have the [Folder Admin role](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders#folder-permissions):

Also, take a look at the “best practices“ [regarding folders IAM permissions](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-folders#best-practices-folders-iam), this may help to configure them.